# How to add a different fields inside the array object if conditions meet in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```json
[
  {
    "Empname": "Doug",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
          },
          {
            "Categoryid": 233,
            "Categoryname": "Maths"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Empname": "stark",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
          },
          {
            "Categoryid": 144,
            "Categoryname": "language "
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here I want to insert two fields at same time if it meets the following conditions

if this collection contains

```json
{
            "Categoryid": 233,
            "Categoryname": "Maths",
}
```

and

```json
{
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
}
```

I have to add extra fields like this
output:

```json
{
           "Categoryid": 233,
            "Categoryname": "Maths",
            "CategoryLabel": "Mex",
            "CategoryCode": "Mex-D"
}
 {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
            "CategoryLabel": "Hex",
            "CategoryCode": "Hex-D",
          }
```

---

Complete Output:

```json
  {
    "Empname": "Doug",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
            "CategoryLabel": "Hex",
            "CategoryCode": "Hex-D",
          },
          {
            "Categoryid": 233,
            "Categoryname": "Maths",
            "CategoryLabel": "Mex",
            "CategoryCode": "Mex-D"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Empname": "stark",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science",
            "CategoryLabel": "Hex",
            "CategoryCode": "Hex-D",
          }          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add two new fields inside the array object if conditions meet in mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907848/add-two-new-fields-inside-the-array-object-if-conditions-meet-in-mongodb-collect)

Comment: Yes but I am expecting like I have to add 2  new fields dynamically inside the array object depends on the categoryid and categoryname fields present inside the array object.